# ffmpeg ideal format to convert videos using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jwplayer

well the thing is, I intend to do a conversion of videos in the following qualities 240p, 360, 480p and 720p

I researched a lot out there and got some codes to use, but there's something wrong some videos takes several hours to convert and shows this message.

```
[libvo_aacenc @ 000000000032a0a0] Bitrate 32 is extremely low, maybe you mean 32k
The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s
```

but some videos converts normally what I want is if someone has done some code that converts faster and is lighter in player jwplayer

```
ffmpeg -i discovery_channel.webm -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f mp4 -s 640x240 -preset ultrafast video240.mp4

ffmpeg -i discovery_channel.webm -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f mp4 -s 640x360 video360.mp4

ffmpeg -i FIDELIDADE.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 640x720 -preset ultrafast video720.mp4

ffmpeg -i FIDELIDADE.mp4 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 video720.mp4

ffmpeg -i discovery_channel.webm -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 video360.mp4
```

the last code I like most because it makes the conversion from vertical to 720 pixels, and does nothing in the horizontal video.

I tested several codes, when some take too much when video with the extension "webm"

anyway if someone has a good code that works in jwplayer and is unversão serves to any video.

Comment: Why do you want so many video sizes? You're trying to apply 32 bits/s for the audio. That's extremely low. I'm assuming you mean `-ab 32k`, but that is also low; especially for the particular AAC encoder you're using. Please include the complete ffmpeg console output for one of the commands. ffmpeg command-line usage questions should be asked at [su] since [so] is limited to programming questions. I voted for migration so please do not cross-post a duplicate question in [su].

Comment: thanks for the tip, but tell me something depending on the output format is a good format standard for audio ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Also, you should include my name with `@LordNeckbeard` so I get notified of your replies.

Comment: @Offboard What happend ? did you found any good solution ?